# Are custom angular libraries upward compatible?

Tags: compatibility, angular12, angular-library

Is custom angular library developed using 9.1.x upward compatible with version 12.2.0?

I am trying to use library developed using angular 9.1.x in angular project which uses angular 12.2.0
I am getting the below errors:

```
Error: node_modules/@my-auth/implicit/lib/implicit-flow-provider.d.ts:22:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

22     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ImpFProvider, [null, null, { optional: true; }]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/implicit/lib/implicit-flow-provider.d.ts:23:22 - error TS2724: '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?

23     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDef<ImpFProvider>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/implicit/lib/implicit-flow-provider.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta'.

9     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta<ImpFProviderModule, never, [typeof i1.CommonModule, typeof i2.HttpClientModule, typeof i3.AUtilsModule], never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/b-utils.module.d.ts:5:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta'.

5     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta<AUtilsModule, never, [typeof i1.CommonModule, typeof i2.HttpClientModule], never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/b-utils-service.d.ts:23:3m21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

23     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<AUtilsService, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/b-utils-service.d.ts:24:22 - error TS2724: '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?

24     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDef<AUtilsService>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/auth-provider-factory.d.ts:8:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

8     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<AuthProFactory, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/auth-provider-factory.d.ts:9:22 - error TS2724: '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?

9     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDef<AuthProFactory>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/b2c-token-builder.service.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

9     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<BTBuilderService, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/b2c-token-builder.service.d.ts:10:22 - error TS2724: '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?

10     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDef<BTBuilderService>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/storage-utils.service.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

9     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<StUtilsService, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/services/storage-utils.service.d.ts:10:22 - error TS2724: '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?

10     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDef<StUtilsService>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/types/auth-provider.d.ts:52:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

52     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Auth1Provider, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@my-auth/types/lib/types/auth-provider.d.ts:53:22 - error TS2724: '"C:/Users/admin/myAngularApp2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?
```

Comment: Googling your error leads to this. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42444

Comment: That is regarding @ngx-meta/core, but I am getting an issue regarding @angular/core

Comment: I have tried below workarounds like:-

[1]added below in tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions":{
 [...]
 "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"]
    }
}

[2] Delete folder node_modules then run the npm i command
[3] Suggestion was to update @angular/core and @angular/cli from 12.2.9 -> 12.2.10 
[4] Npx ngcc
[5] Npm audit fix 
[6] npm i install-peers@1.0.3


but none of them are working

Comment: The issue seems the same: "using internal Ivy instructions for v9, which means that the library can only be used in an application using the exact same Angular version"

Comment: Did you fixed this. i am also facing same issue